# how to evaluate if a rectangle fits or not in an image with some "obstacles"

Tags: python

As main data I've an image already converted in a list of lists of tuples(r,g,b) defined `start_img`,
where each list is a line (y) of pixels and each list inside y contains the actual pixel value (x) as a tuple (r,g,b)
the image is made up as follow:

- Some rectangles: each one has a different value for color, width, height.
- The others pixels are just `rgb(0, 0, 0)` pixels.

### I CAN'T USE EXTERNAL LIBRARIES

1st goal
I'm looking for a way to find each rectangle already in the image and store it as `x,y,h,w,r,g,b`.
where (`x,y`) is the position of the rectangle and referes to the first top left pixel.

```
example
XXBBBBB
XXBBBXX
XXBBBXX
```

where `X` is a non black pixel and `B` stands for a black pixel

---

2nd goal
given a list of others rectangles I should check if i could or not fit them (one by one).

FIRST GOAL!!
in the example above there are 2 rectangles and my function should return

```
output:0,0,3,2,color.
       5,5,2,2,color.
```

where for the first line 0,0 stands for (`x,y`), (2,2) stans for **width**, **height**, and **color**, if it's red for example there's should be this tuple `(255,0,0)`.

So here I was thinking to use a nested for loop to iterate on each pixel and if it finds a color different then black it should increase the width and store the starting pixel in a dict like this
(`x,y`) as key and (`w,h,r,g,b`).

Now since it's a rectangle i can assume that if i find at (0,0),(1,0) red as color, when i'm then iterating on (1,0) if it's red it should assume that (1,1) it must be red and (1,2) must be black (as 0,2... ofc there's the rectangles are always slightly divided by at least a black pixel).
ofc this is just an idea i'm not even sure if it's a good method.

---

SECOND GOAL!!
For this task i'm just looking for a function that return True or False.

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this is checking neighbours recursively. This way, one can extract regions with equal color. Afterwards, one can check by the number of elements if the identified region is indeed a rectangle.

For this example I have used "X" and "Y" as color, and "B" as black, but those can be easily replaced by rgb tuples.

```py
img_str = """
XXBBBBB
XXBBBYY
XXBBBYY
"""

# split into list of lists
img = [[letter for letter in line] for line in
       img_str.strip().splitlines()]


def get_region(img_list, x, y, color, black):
    """ recursive helper function to identify regions of same color """
    region = []
    try:  # to get a pixel of suitable color
        test_pixel = img_list[y][x]
        if test_pixel != color:
            return []  # color not suitable
    except IndexError:
        return []  # outside of image
    img_list[y][x] = black  # mask the found pixel (elsewise one would find it again later on)
    region.append((x, y))  # add found pixel to region
    region.extend(get_region(img_list, x + 1, y, color, black))  # look at left-side neighbour recursively
    region.extend(get_region(img_list, x, y + 1, color, black))  # look at down-side neighbour recursively
    return region


def get_rectangle_dim(region):
    """ check if identified region is a rectangle and return dimensionality"""
    min_x = min(region, key=lambda t: t[0])[0]
    max_x = max(region, key=lambda t: t[0])[0]
    min_y = min(region, key=lambda t: t[1])[1]
    max_y = max(region, key=lambda t: t[1])[1]
    width = (max_x - min_x + 1)
    height = (max_y - min_y + 1)
    if width * height == len(region):
        return min_x, min_y, width, height
    # else this returns None implicitly


potential_rectangles = []
black = "B"
# loop over rows and columns
for y in range(len(img)):
    for x in range(len(img[0])):
        # identify target color
        if (color := img[y][x]) == black:
            continue  # skip black regions
        if region := get_region(img, x, y, color, black):
            potential_rectangles.append((region, color))  # add found regions

# filter all regions for rectangles
rectangles = []
for potential_rectangle, color in potential_rectangles:
    if rectangle := get_rectangle_dim(potential_rectangle):
        rectangles.append(rectangle + (color,))

# show end result
print(rectangles)
```